# tkinter: Is it possible to use native Tcl/Tk tklib's ctext widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have come across an interesting widget ([source code](https://core.tcl.tk/tklib/dir?ci=a6c2dcb8c9929572&name=modules/ctext)) which seems to support syntax highlighting and a bunch of other stuff. I would like to use it in my tkinter app, however I'm not sure if that's entirely possible. I know that you can use `tkinter.eval()` to evaluate raw Tcl/Tk code, but I'm not sure what am I supposed to do after I evaluate the entire source code/place it somewhere - how can I instantiate the widget and actually use it?

Comment: you could open `tkinter` source code (path to code `import tkinter ; print(tkinter.__file__)`) and see how it works.

Comment: yes, it's possible. Tkinter is nothing but a thin wrapper around tcl/tk code, and ctext is just more tcl/tk code.

Comment: @BryanOakley: do you mind creating a little example how can one go about this?

Comment: @mentalita:  yes, I mind. It's going to be a lot of work and I don't have time to do it. stackoverflow isn't a free coding service. I recommend you start with a single .tcl file that has just a couple lines of code, and figure out how to use that in tkinter. Once you've figured that out,  you can try including this widget.

Comment: @BryanOakley: if it's a lot of work - sure, no worries. In any case, no need to take it that seriously and get offended or whatever and use 'free coding service' argument. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I happen to have the source for ctext (which is part of tklib) so I can let my Tcl library know about the additional package location using TCLLIBPATH environment variable. Then it can just be loaded. However, you will need to do some interfacing to python

```
pat@uknml7167 ~ $ TCLLIBPATH=/opt/src/tklib/modules python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> root.tk.call('package','require','ctext')
'3.3'
```

So the short answer is 'yes'.

There is a bit of an example for [tkribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30621362/291641) on this site. I'm sure there are better examples of using a native Tk package around.

A quick demo based on the above:

```
class Ctext(tk.Widget):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Widget.__init__(self, master, 'ctext')

ctext = Ctext(root)
ctext.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
```

A tkinter wrapper class has been uploaded to [github](https://github.com/patthoyts/tkinter-ctext) along with a small demo script.

Comment: cool, thanks. I'll have a look at the example, I believe it should not be too much effort/too tough to create a little Python wrapper.

Comment: also, might I ask how do you 'happen to have it'? more specifically, I'm asking where should I place it on my computer, since it can't find it at the moment. My `/opt/` doesn't have `src` at all. What am I missing here?

Comment: I have it cloned from the Tk fossil repository as I sometimes do Tk maintenance.