# Python Ribbon Application using Tkinter

Tags: python, visual-studio, dll, tkinter, ribbon

I want to make a ribbon style application using Python Tkinter.

The wrapper in the following thread answered by patthoyts seems to work very well:

- [Is there a way to use ribbon toolbars in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615579/is-there-a-way-to-use-ribbon-toolbars-in-tkinter)

I am struggling however to create the .dll for my own ribbon design. I have used [RibbonWinForms](https://github.com/RibbonWinForms/RibbonWinForms)  addon to Visual Studio 2017 to export a dll of a draft ribbon project. RibbonWinForms seems works very well.

Replacing the dll downloaded from patthoyts (first link) with my exported dll (and renaming the file accordingly) doesn't work and yields the error (_tkinter.TclError: cannot find symbol "Tkribbon_Init").
I have saved the various files (including the exported .dll with origional names) from Visual Studio [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/clouddrive/share/N81IUbeFRNqdlBUe5VCC2Km8yPAN1lfUJnYgJmE48zx).

Why does the code below work with patthoyts dll and not mine? (See link above for .dll's.

I would be very grateful if someone can advise what code changes or dll export changes are required to get this working?

Or, if I am over complicating this and there is a much simpler way to achieve a ribbon application coded in python that would be great?

For reference patthoyts code is below, and his dll is also saved at the amazon link above also:

```
from tkinter import Widget
from os import path

class Ribbon(Widget):
    def __init__(self, master, kw=None):
        self.version = master.tk.call('package','require','tkribbon')
        self.library = master.tk.eval('set ::tkribbon::library')
        Widget.__init__(self, master, 'tkribbon::ribbon', kw=kw)

    def load_resource(self, resource_file, resource_name='APPLICATION_RIBBON'):
        """Load the ribbon definition from resources.

        Ribbon markup is compiled using the uicc compiler and the resource included
        in a dll. Load from the provided file."""
        self.tk.call(self._w, 'load_resources', resource_file)
        self.tk.call(self._w, 'load_ui', resource_file, resource_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from tkinter import *
    def main():
        root = Tk()
        r = Ribbon(root)
        name = 'APPLICATION_RIBBON'
        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            resource = sys.argv[1]
            if len(sys.argv) > 2:
                name = sys.argv[2]
        else:
            resource = path.join(r.library, 'libtkribbon1.0.dll')
        r.load_resource(resource, name)
        t = Text(root)
        r.grid(sticky=(N,E,S,W))
        t.grid(sticky=(N,E,S,W))
        root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        root.mainloop()
    main()
```

Comment: You haven't asked an actual question in your question. As it stands it is unclear as to what you need assistance with here beyond "Fix my code for free please". Please, can you explicitly state your question?

Comment: I've added question marks to make the questions clearer

Comment: Additional clear question added. I'm not expecting anyone to fix my code, just help me understand why it doesn't work so I can fix it.